# Firebase query maximum limit with FEventTypeValue?

Tags: ios, firebase

Is there a limit for the size of a snapshot of a FEventTypeValue?

I am planning to use it to get up to 10000 item, is it relevant to do so?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Getting multiple items with a `FEventTypeValue` is a bad idea in general and grows progressively worse as the number of items increases. I would *seriously* recommend that you switch to `FEventTypeChildAdded` when dealing with (especially a large) number of children. That said: the limits are documented here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/understanding-data.html

Comment: Thank you this answer! Btw Firebase is great as well as its support ! :)